# Magento - How to edit getChildHtml('addto')

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Good morning, I need to edit html

```
getChildHtml ('addto')
```

I have already enabled hint, to try to find out, and I can not find the html, does anyone know where it is?

Comment: What are you actually looking for? The HTML code for the "Add to Cart" button or every file where it's called? Is this Magento 1 or 2?

Comment: i Need button add to wishlist, magento 1.9

Comment: Try `/app/design/frontend/{{vendor}}/{{theme}}/template/wishlist/button/tocart.phtml` (replacing {{vendor}} and {{theme}} as required of course)

Comment: ok, thanks, im try

Answer (score 0):

For example: (magento 2)

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml (part of file)

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto" />
    </block>
</block>
```

Inside `Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml` you can call `$this->getChildHtml('product_list')` (name of block inside this)

And it will render

- block:

> Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct

- with template:

> Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml

it that place.

*P.S.: Magento 1.9 has same architecture of calling children blocks*

Comment: *"Magento 1.9 has same architecture"* ... it really doesn't.

Comment: @CD001 It means about calling `getChildHtml()` function

Comment: Yeah - but what the OP is trying to find (I think) is the corresponding HTML code that's pulled in *when* you call that method... and *that* code is located in completely different places in M1 and M2. I might be wrong though.

Comment: I just showed architecture. He can find it by himself, with knowing of blocks architecture